# OpenJDK (Amzon Corretto) && using fonts from an additional directory

Tags: java, fonts

We have a Java written application which is executed with `amazon-corretto-8.342.07.1-windows-x64-jdk` for which we do need additional fonts. As we do not want pollute the Amazon Corretto directories with these additional fonts, we try to use them from an additional directory specified on the command line as:

```
-Dsun.java2d.fontpath=append:C:/TEMP/fonts/fallback

or

-Dappendedfontpath=C:/TEMP/fonts/fallback
```

but without any luck. How could we get to the correct notation flags for this purpose?

Comment: what is the windows version? have you tried backslash as path separator?

Comment: It's with Win 11. We tried both, / and \ as path separator. Also -DJAVA_FONTS=... does not do the trick.